# Run sequential requests with simultaneous users using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am testing the CRUD operation and my test plan looks like below :

```
  Test Plan 
  |_Login 
  |_Create 
  |_Read 
  |_Update 
  |_Delete
```

Now I have 100 users. I want all the 100 users to finish login, then go to Create operation ,all 100 users finish create operation, then go to Read operation ...

I used the loop controller to execute the same request 100 times with only one user.But this doesn't cover the scenario of 100 simultaneous users logging in(hitting a url).Is there any way in  jmeter to perform the above explained procedure?

Comment: did  you get the solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler after each of the requests
2. Add a [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) as a child of each Test Action sampler and set `Number of Simulated Users to Group by` to the number of threads in your Thread Group

[image: JMeter Synchronizing Timer]

Test Action samplers will act as a rendezvous points for all threads and they will not be displayed in the test results.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with 3 Thread Groups

- Check in Test Plan checkbox `Run Thread Groups Consecutively`
- Login Thread Group with Number of Threads 100 - Add [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) with Number 100 and Timeout 0
- Create Thread Group with Number of Threads 100 - Add [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) with Number 100 and Timeout 0
- Read Thread Group with Number of Threads 100 - Add [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) with Number 100 and Timeout 0

Each Thread Group can read users from CSV/file.